# Why does it take so long to log in automatically?

Tags: support, login

Sometimes, when I go to an SE site that I'm not logged in to, it takes several seconds or a page refresh before I'm automatically logged in. Is there a technical reason for this?

Comment: They prioritize page loading and being able to *use* the site above automatic login.

Comment: @Pollyanna: Do you mean that there is a lack of server resources or a lack of developer time?

Comment: @Pollyanna - I mean that the checks for stackauth.com and your HTML5 cache are *probably* performed after the page is done loading, meaning that they wait for images and other content to load prior to doing the check.  I haven't checked, but that it is most likely reason.  This is likely a design decision, as most viewers don't need/require the auto login (coming from google, etc) and delaying the visible site content to check the DB at stackauth against the HTML5 client side cache would be slower for the majority of users.